# Using bibleref inside a section title

Tags: sectioning, bibleref

The [`bibleref`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref/) package does not work when a reference is called inside the title of a section. The following error is raised:

```
Argument of \@sect has an extra }
```

Same inside a caption. Does anyone knows how to overcome this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{bibleref}

\begin{document}

Here a reference in the text which works: \bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3)

\section{Here a reference within a title: \bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3) } % Don't work

\begin{table}
\caption{Here a reference within a caption: \bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3) } % Don't work
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `\protect` those "special" references:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{bibleref}

\begin{document}

Here a reference in the text which works: \bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3)

\section{Here a reference within a title: \protect\bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3) }

\begin{table}
\caption{Here a reference within a caption: \protect\bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3) }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

## Explanation

As there is already a great and very detailed answer [here (What is
the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4747/97512) by @mpg,
I'll try my luck with a not-so-detailed, but hopefully still helpful
explanation. In this answer I try to look at it by example rather
than the full details. If you want to know more in detail, read the
linked answer, or feel free to ask.

The issue is kind of easily addressed (if you can track it down),
but the origin is a little technical. The problem can be more easily
looked at by observing the auxiliary file that is produced while
compiling. It contains, e.g., the section names and captions. This
is needed, because you might want to print, e.g., a table of contents
(or a table of tables), and the section names (or caption names) have
to be displayed in there as well. So, these sections and captions
can occur twice in the same document, in different places. This is
why one calls them "moving" commands. The text is copied/"moved"
to another place in your document.

Assuming your document is called
`doc.tex`, latex writes a file called `doc.aux`. When latex writes
to this file, it usually *expands* the macros. If you observe the
content of `doc.aux`, you will see what happens:

Without `\protect`ing the macro, it contains

```
\relax 
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Here a reference within a caption: \let \@bv@restore \relax \def {}Genesis\let \let \let  \let \def  {\BRbookof }\def \BRbooknumberstyle  \def {\BRepistletothe }\def \BRepistlenumberstyle  \let \@@protect \let \@unexpandable@protect \afterassignment \let \@@protect \edef \BRbooktitlestyle {\BRbookof Genesis}{\BRbooktitlestyle {Genesis}}\let \let \let  \let \let \reserved@d = (\def \par }}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Here a reference within a title: \let \@bv@restore \relax \def {}Genesis\let \let \let  \let \def  {\BRbookof }\def \BRbooknumberstyle  \def {\BRepistletothe }\def \BRepistlenumberstyle  \let \@@protect \let \@unexpandable@protect \afterassignment \let \@@protect \edef \BRbooktitlestyle {\BRbookof Genesis}{\BRbooktitlestyle {Genesis}}\let \let \let  \let \let \reserved@d = (\def \par }{1}}
```

This "gibberish" you see here is the expanded `\bibleverse` macro,
i.e., how it is defined. In contrast to the `\protect`ed version:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Here a reference within a caption: \bibleverse {Gn}(1:1-3) }}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Here a reference within a title: \bibleverse {Gn}(1:1-3) }{1}}
```

You might notice that the `\protect` actually does what it's named
after. It *protects* the following macro from expansion. This is
needed, as this auxiliary file is read in again to display, e.g.,
the toc.

In short, you need to preserve the original macro without expansion
in order to make it work.

## Robust commands

Instead of protecting every `\bibleverse` in a moving command, as
@Mico pointed out, you can follow a different path: Making the macro
"robust". This actually makes the macro "self-protecting", so you
don't need to take care of it manually.

To make a macro robust, you can use `\robustify{\macro}` provided by
the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % provides the \robustify command

\usepackage{bibleref}
\robustify{\bibleverse} % makes \bibleverse work in sections and captions

\begin{document}

Here a reference in the text which works: \bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3)

\section{Here a reference within a title: \bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3) }

\begin{table}
\caption{Here a reference within a caption: \bibleverse{Gn}(1:1-3) }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This works as well, and you don't have to take care of every occurence
in a caption or section. Whether you should cite (frequently) in a
section title or not... Well that's another topic, but by "robustifying"
the `\bibleverse` macro, you're free to do it without having to
`\protect` it manually.

Thanks @Mico for that nice and helpful comment :)

Comment: +1. You may want to provide a bit more information as to what `\protect` does or, alternatively, explain that "fragile" commands (such as `\bibleverse`) mustn't occur in the arguments of "moving" commands such as `\section` and `\caption` -- *unless" they are either `\protect`ed or made "robust", e.g., via a `\robustify` directive. (Making a fragile command robust is probably the way to go if it needs to occur several times in a document in "moving arguments".)

Comment: Thank you @Mico for the `\robustify` tip, this is what I need. If you write it in a separate answer, or if @nox amend it, I could accept the answer.

Comment: @Tobard - I'm sure that nox will edit and amend his/her answer shortly and include the idea of using `\robustify`. (The `\robustify` macro is provided by the `etoolbox` package.)

Comment: @Tobard See my updated answer.

Comment: the next version of bibleref will robustify directly the \bibleverse macro.